# Delegates - does the delegate return type have to match the method it is delegating too?

Tags: c#, delegates

I expect this to sound like an obvious question but, does the delegate return type have to match the return type of the method it is delegating too?

EG, like this:

```
public static void Save()
    {
        TS ts = new TS(SaveToDatabase);
    }

    public delegate void TS();

    private static void SaveToDatabase()
    { }
```

where this will never work

```
public static void Save()
    {
        TS ts = new TS(SaveToDatabase);
    }

    public delegate string TS();

    private static void SaveToDatabase()
    { }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, It has to return the same type and have the same parameters.
In other words, the function and the delegate declaration must have the same signature.

Example:

```
    //Declare delegate (return double with double param)
    public delegate double Squared(double x);

    public class Circle
    {
        private double _radius;


        public static double ValueTimesValue(double Value)
        {
            return Value * Value;
        }

        public double Area(Squared sqd)
        {
            return sqd(_radius) * Math.PI;
        }

        public void CircleCharacteristics()
        {
            Squared Sq = new Squared(ValueTimesValue);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** `If you see the sample code, Squared Delegate and ValueTimesValue function have the same return type and parameters.`

Comment: Thank you - my progress had shown this but when new to this, it is so complicated. Thank you

Comment: If you see the sample code, Squared Delegate and ValueTimesValue function have the same return type and parameters.

Answer (score 5):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> A delegate lets you pass a function as a parameter. The type safety of
>   delegates requires the function you pass as a delegate to have the
>   same signature as the delegate declaration.

And another quote from [C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664603%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

A method and a delegate type are compatible if both of the following are true:

- They have the same number or parameters, with the same types, in the same order, with the same parameter modifiers.
- **Their return types are the same.**

I think it's very good description of compatibility conditions. And as you can see, your code violates second condition, which produces compiler error.

Comment: I could read that forever and not understand it  :) Thank you. I had read the MSDN and have been using their examples. It is slowly starting to make sense now.

Comment: @DaveRook I'v added important part of C# specification to my answer, which describes what conditions method should satisfy

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, a delegate is a template for a method (hope I don't get bashed too hard for the oversimplification). If you want a visualization, think of it like a lock, and the physical implementation is like a key. A key fits a certain lock and fails in a different lock. Just as a key won't fit in the wrong lock, a method that applies a different template (signature) fails.

So, yes, you need the right signature for the method you wish to "delegate work to". If you want to think more in software terms, a delegate is a contract for the physical implementation it represents, much like an interface is a contract for the actual methods it represents. They are very similar concepts.

Comment: +1 for the comparison between an interface - now I totally get it! Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help Dave. Purist may hate me, but finding analogs often makes things easier to understand. :-)

Comment: I believe in the earlier Java days, which is arguably stricter OO than C#, there wasn't anything to fulfill the role of delegates. Interfaces are a great comparison because they would have literally been necessary to implement deligate-like-functionality. You would register an object with a class that implements some 'Single Method EventInterface' and call the interface's method when triggering the event from the host. You could even nurse a collection of 'EventInterface' implementations to facilitate multiple subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

Actually not necessarily. The types of arguments and result must only match. So you can do this:

```
class Argument : BaseArgument    {    }

class BaseArgument    {    }

class BaseResult    {    }

class Result : BaseResult    {    }

delegate BaseResult MyDelegate(Argument argument);

class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
     var d1 = new MyDelegate(Method1);

    }

    Result Method1(BaseArgument a)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

By match I mean covariance for return type so method can return more specialized (derived) type then delegate is declaring - delegate requires BaseResult so Result is OK.
And contravariance for arguments so delegate says that Argument will be provided so method can declare BaseArgument as parameter becaulse Argument is BaseArgument.

Comment: Yes, polymorphism is used by mechanisms named covariance and contravariance.

Answer (score 0):

Great question!  And yes you do; however, you can use a generic to make it more flexible.

```
namespace GenericDelegates
{
    public delegate T MyDelegate<out T>();

    public class Blah
    {
        public static int IntMethod()
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public static string StringMethod()
        {
            return "hello";
        }
    }

    public class Blah1
    {
        public void GenericMethod<T>(MyDelegate<T> myDelegate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myDelegate?.Invoke().ToString());
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var blah = new Blah1();
            blah.GenericMethod(Blah.IntMethod);
            blah.GenericMethod(Blah.StringMethod);
        }
    }
}
```